# How to configure MongoDB in Spring 2.5.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I used to have this `@Configuration` class that extends `AbstractMongoConfiguration`.

I want to upgrade to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Once I'm doing that I see that this class cannot be resolved.

What's the alternative?

Note: I'd like to have multiple configurations for different profiles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AbstractMongoConfiguration` was [deprecated in Spring Data MongoDB 2.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoConfiguration.html) in favour of [AbstractMongoClientConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoClientConfiguration.html). It was then removed in Spring Data MongoDB 3.0. You should replace your usage of `AbstractMongoConfiguration` with `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration`.